# What is the "Organize Usings" menu ID in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vspackage, vs-extensibility

I'm creating a Visual Studio 2010 extension using a Package template, not an Add-in.

I want to add a menu item to the "Organize Usings" menu group that appears when you right-click in a .cs file. To do this, I need the guid and the id of that menu group.

```
<Button guid="myCmdSet" id="myButton" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu (I think?)" id="???" />
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
    <Strings>
      <CommandName>myCommand</CommandName>
      <ButtonText>Do Stuff</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
```

I have looked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165988.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514114.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsmenus.idm_vs_ctxt_codewin.aspx). Basically all around MSDN. Are these published, and does anyone know what they are?

EDIT: I found the related menu via [this method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/f87af77f-d431-4246-9631-de92c6533bfb), but I still don't have a way to find the menu group GUID/ID, which is what I really want.

Comment: Try recording a temporary macro and execute that command. It should encode into the macro.

Comment: That doesn't work because I'm not trying to get a command ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG, I've spend 3 hours on this :D Here's the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>
  <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>
  <Extern href="msobtnid.h"/>
  <Commands package="guidVSPackage1Pkg">
    <Buttons>      
      <Button guid="guidCSharpGrpId" id="mySuperCommand" priority="0x0200" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidCSharpGrpId" id="IDG_CSHARP_CTX_ORGANIZE" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <CommandName>mySuperCommand</CommandName>
          <ButtonText>My super command</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
    </Buttons>
    <Bitmaps>
      <Bitmap guid="guidImages" href="Resources\Images_32bit.bmp" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPicSearch, bmpPicX, bmpPicArrows"/>
    </Bitmaps>
  </Commands>
  <Symbols>
    <!-- This is the package guid. -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidVSPackage1Pkg" value="{F066e284-dcab-11d2-b551-00c04f68d4db}" />
    <GuidSymbol name="guidCSharpGrpId" value="{5d7e7f65-a63f-46ee-84f1-990b2cab23f9}">
      <IDSymbol name="IDG_CSHARP_CTX_ORGANIZE" value="0x3618" />
      <IDSymbol name="mySuperCommand" value="0x0100" />
    </GuidSymbol>
    <GuidSymbol name="guidImages" value="{cff24f4c-767f-48ee-aff4-6bdf8218cba0}" >
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

You must place **guidCSharpGrpId** and **IDG_CSHARP_CTX_ORGANIZE** because they're not available in "standard" set of id's. By "standard" I'mean those placed in *VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc* directory within *.h files. They're hidden in *cslangsvcui.dll* library.

To get these ID's I've used **VS Command Table PowerToy**. You can download it from here:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/VSCTPowerToy

Check this also as this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/697245ac-1596-4d6a-b55c-f5b01b69a583

In case that this solution won't work for you because some guids, etc. I've put zipped project on my SkyDrive:
https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=6A19F3A9B7B8E017&id=6A19F3A9B7B8E017!16486

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yea, that social.msdn forum link is actually my question :) I've had the solution for a while now but couldn't find a way to delete the bounty. But since you put the time in...